# DRY, Short, and Conventional helper which returns multiple lines of HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for the DRYest, most conventional, and shortest way to write this helper.

I have something like this at the top of each index view file:

```
<%= page_header "Blog", "My thoughts on things" %>
```

And the corresponding helper:

```
def page_header(title=nil, subtitle=nil)
  header = ''
  header += content_tag(:h1, title) if title.present?
  header += content_tag(:h3, subtitle) if subtitle.present?
  return header.html_safe
end
```

It works, but it's ugly and I know there is a better way, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for a partial.

`app/views/shared/_page_header.html.erb`:

```
<% if title.present? %>
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
<% end %>

<% if subtitle.present? %>
  <h3><%= subtitle %></h3>
<% end %>
```

And the helper would be:

```
def page_header(title = nil, subtitle = nil)
  render "shared/page_header", :title => title, :subtitle => subtitle
end
```

You can also look at [cells](http://cells.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like:

```
def page_header(title=nil, subtitle=nil)
  [
    title && content_tag(:h1, title),
    subtitle && content_tag(:h3, subtitle)
  ].join.html_safe
end
```

While not technically equivalent - that'll include the tags even if the title is not-nil but blank - it'll probably do what you want in this case.

If you want to get fancy:

```
MAPPINGS = [[:title, "h1"], [:subtitle, "h3"]]
def page_header(options = {})
  MAPPINGS.map {|e| options[e[0]] && content_tag(e[1], options[e[0]]) }.join.html_safe
end
```

Then, you can call:

```
page_header :title => "Foobar", :subtitle => "Woohoo"
```

And it'll work. I'd argue that the second helper is uglier though.